# Pyramid order + strategy.exit for TP/SL

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using pyramid order such as 20 entry position and when I use strategy.exit for TP/SL it will trigger 20times, Is it possible to 1 trigger for all order ?

Entry Order: Code

```
strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short, qty=qty, alert_message = '{"position_to_open":{"side" :"Short"}}', comment=comment_open_short)
```

this is my code for TP/SL

```
strategy.exit(id = 'Short Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', qty_percent = 100, limit = na(tp)?na:tp, stop = na(sl)?na:sl)
```

Thank you.

[image]

try to use close_all it work for 1 trigger but can not work with exact TP/SL price on current bar

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Each entry is a separate entry in the order book so when your TP or SL is hit, `strategy.exit()` will close them one by one.